# Prolog - apply arguments with maplist

Tags: debugging, prolog, maplist

I would like to understand what could be my error with this piece of code for custom predicate for maplist with a list of list :

```
generateProjection(TableOrTables/Selectors, Row, Result) :- 
    writeln(kiki),
    writeln(TableOrTables),
    writeln(Selectors),
    writeln(Row),
    Result = 1/2.

compute_projection(Rows, TableOrTables, Selectors, Result) :- 
    writeln(hello),
    writeln(Rows),
    writeln(Selectors),
    maplist(
        generateProjection(TableOrTables/Selectors),
        Rows,
        Result
    ).
```

This query works :

```
generateProjection(foo/[foo/bar, foo/baz], [1, 2], Z).
```

whereas this one fails :

```
compute_projection([[1, 2], [3, 4]], foo, [foo/bar, foo/baz], _4552/_4554).
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your second query:

```
?- compute_projection([[1,2],[3,4]], foo, [foo/bar,foo/baz], _A/_B).
```

`maplist/3` relates two **lists**.
Now let's look at the predicate definition again:

```
compute_projection(Rows, TableOrTables, Selectors, Result) :- 
    maplist(generateProjection(TableOrTables/Selectors),
            Rows,
            Result).
```

So `Result` is a list but the query demands a term of the form `_/_`.

This is why your query cannot succeed.

Comment: What I wanted to do in compute_projection is to generate a list of \_/\_ generated from the generateProjection (so that I can use a findall on that). How can I fix it ? Use another variable ?

Comment: @jy95. You are already doing that. So `Result` has the form `[]` or `[_/_]` or `[_/_, _/_]` etc...  Run the query again after replacing `_A/_B` with a variable...

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)